# usar 'where' con 'like' en una realacion eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

hola tengo dos modelos Movimiento y Cuenta

En el modelo Movimiento tengo la siguiente relacion.

```
public function cuenta()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Cuenta::class);
}
```

Lo que busco es traer todos los Movimientos con su relación Cuenta, en la consulta con Cuenta debe cumplir con el nombre del banco, y el nombre del titular.

El detalle esta en el titular de la cuenta, el 'LIKE' y los comodines del ultimo WHERE no funciona y no encuentra ninguna coicidencia.

```
$movimientos = Movimiento::where('fecha', $fecha)
->where('status','NUEVO')->with('cuenta')->get()
->where('cuenta.banco', $banco)
->where('cuenta.titular','LIKE','%'.$titular.'%');
```

Si quito el 'like' y los comodines y paso el la variable $titular tal y como esta en la base de datos si me devuelve los registros correspondientes.

```
$movimientos = Movimiento::where('fecha', $fecha)
->where('status','NUEVO')->with('cuenta')->get()
->where('cuenta.banco', $banco)
->where('cuenta.titular', $titular);
```

Comment: no entiendo, cual es el problema en si que te arroja esta consulta?

Comment: este ultimo where no funciona, no encuentra registros en la base de datos where('cuenta.titular','LIKE','%'.$titular.'%'), pero si uso  where('cuenta.titular',$titular) si encuentra los registros pero el string debe ser exactaente igual a como esta en la base de datos.

Answer (score 1):

La función `with` puede contener un array como parámetro, dicho array puede contener un `callback` en donde debes hacer las consultas para tu **cuenta**, de la siguiente manera:

```
$movimientos = Movimiento::where('fecha', $fecha)
->where('status','NUEVO')->with(['cuenta'=>function($query) use ($banco,$titular){
    $query->where('banco', $banco)->where('titular','LIKE','%'.$titular.'%');
}])->get();
```

De esa forma deberia de funcionar tu consulta.

Comment: Pero el indica tener problemas con el operador like y con %%

Comment: Y le estoy mostrando una forma alterna de hacer la consulta.